# Redefine "this" within a function prototype and run it with new parameters

Tags: javascript, prototype, this, call, bind

I have a function prototype that loads data from a path. The trick is that I need to change the path afterward. I tried call, apply, bind and even assign but as I am a novice I did not find the solution.

Here a sample of my code :

```
Chat.prototype.loadMessages = function() {

    this.messagesRef = this.database;

    var setMessage = function(data) {
    var val = data.val();
    this.displayMessage(data.key, val.name, val.text);
    }.bind(this);

};

var chat = new Chat
function setPath (newpath) {
chat.loadMessages.messageRef = newpath; // I guess, it is where I'm wrong...
chat.loadMessages(); // It should load messages from the new path in my chat container.
}
```

As I said I also tried :

```
chat.loadMessages.call(newpath);
```

or

```
 var setPath = function(newpath) {
      chat.loadMessages(newpath);
      }.bind(chat);
      setPath();
 chat.loadMessages();
```

But the chat container continues to disclose messages from the old path...

Comment: What about `chat.loadMessages.database = newpath; chat.loadMessages();`? You might need to restore that property afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a function with **loadMessages**, which is fine but you need to pass in a value to set the new path. Is this more of what you were thinking?

```
Chat.prototype.loadMessages = function (newPath) {

    this.messagesRef = newPath || this.database; // if newPath is empty than default to this.database

    var setMessage = function(data) {
    var val = data.val();
    this.displayMessage(data.key, val.name, val.text);
};

var chat = new Chat
function setPath (newpath) {
    chat.loadMessages(newpath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working perfectly and do much simple that what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

This looks a bit convoluted. Just pass `messagesRef` as a parameter and make it default to `this.database`:

```
Chat.prototype.loadMessages = function(messagesRef = this.database) {
    // do whatever is needed with messagesRef
};

chat = new Chat();
chat.loadMessages(); // load from the default location
chat.loadMessages('foobar'); // load from this specific location
```

Comment: It seems that for my case is not working because messageRef is also used in other functions and I need to keep it as prototype with "this.messageRef".